# Spire.XLS Free version Lock worksheet not working for me

Tags: excel

I am trying to use Spire.XLS Free version:
Lock worksheet not working for me. 
It writes the lockedfile.xlsx but I find it is NOT Read-Only when I use it with Kingsoft Spreadsheets.

I am using the following code:
Obviously I am doing some mistake or my understanding is wrong. Kindly help me.

```
Workbook workbook = new Workbook();

workbook.LoadFromFile("unlocked.xlsx");

workbook.Worksheets[0].Range.Style.Locked = true;

workbook.SaveToFile("lockedfile.xlsx");
```

This is used in a C# program in Asp.Net.....

Answer (score 0):

When we protect current sheet/cells without entering a password, it seems MS Excel will set the password as empty by default. So I tried following code and it works. Password won't be required when users want to unprotect the locked sheet.

[image]

```
Workbook workbook = new Workbook();
workbook.LoadFromFile("unlocked.xlsx");

workbook.Worksheets[0].Range.Style.Locked = true;
workbook.Worksheets[0].Protect("", SheetProtectionType.All);

workbook.SaveToFile("lockedfile.xlsx");
```